# Relevance of 'public' constructor in an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, abstract-class

Is there any relevance of a `public` constructor in an abstract class?
I can not think of any possible way to use it, in that case shouldn't it be treated as error by compiler (C#, not sure if other languages allow that).

Sample Code:

```
internal abstract class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {            
    }
}
```

The C# compiler allows this code to compile, while there is no way I can call this contructor from the outside world. It can be called from derived classes only.

So shouldn't it allow `protected` and `private` modifiers only?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260744/abstract-class-constructor-access-modifier

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, a duplicate, although that question is about java. But there's absolutely no difference between jav and C# in this respect (I think).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason for a public constructor for an abstract class. I'd assume that the reason that the compiler doesn't complain is as simple that they just didn't spend time covering that since it really doesn't matter if it's public or protected.

Answer (score 3):

Inside an abstract class, for an instance constructor, modifiers `public`, `protected internal`, and `protected` are all equivalent. Then `internal` is more strict than them, and `private` is the most strict access.

If all instance constructors are `private`, only classes nested inside the class in question can inherit from it.

Note: If no instance constructors are given for a non-static class, then the compiler will generate one by itself. That's a constructor taking zero arguments. If the class is abstract, that auto-generated constructor is `protected`. Otherwise it is `public`.

The only situation I can think of where it makes a difference if an instance constructor of an abstract class is `public` or `protected`, is when you use reflection. As an example, saying

```
ConstructorInfo[] ctors = typeof(Vehicle).GetConstructors();
```

will give an empty array if the sole constructor is `protected`, and a length-1 array if it's `public`. But of course there are overloads that specify `BindingFlags`, so this is not a problem, just something to remember if one uses reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `public` ctor on an abstract class is meaningless and a bit misleading as it will behave as protected in that only derived classes may call it.

A `private` ctor will have *little meaning* outside of interesting edge cases.

A `protected` ctor would make sense if required by derived classes.

Comment: A `private` constructor does makes sense in an abstract class.

Comment: @dan04: Does it make sense in any situation other than when chained from some other constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Dupe: there is another question on SO just like this: [Abstract class constructor access modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260744/abstract-class-constructor-access-modifier)

The answers on that question come down to the same thing in the end: it does not really matter if you declare it `protected` or `public`.

Also there seems to be some discussion about it in literature (e.g. in [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)). This is referenced in this blogpost: [Good design or bad design of abstract class?](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2006/02/22/139019.aspx)

Comment: This question is about C#, and the other is about Java. Therefore this is not a duplicate.